# Javascript namespace init when called from jquery.ready()

Tags: javascript, namespaces

Is the following method wrong way of declaring namespace in Javascript? It is from the book I'm reading and doesn't seem to work in my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mynamespace = {};

if(Drupal.jsEnabled){       
    $(document).ready(mynamespace.init);    
}

mynamespace.init = function() {
    $("#mybutton").bind("click",function(){     
        alert('hello');
    });
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your code is dependent on jQuery. Make sure that is loaded before you run this script. Also, define your function before it gets called. Try this:

```
var mynamespace = {};

mynamespace.init = function() {
    $("#mybutton").bind("click",function(){     
        alert('hello');
    });
}

if(Drupal.jsEnabled){       
    $(document).ready(mynamespace.init);    
}
```

Comment: What jarrett says below is true. JavaScript doesn't have a true namespace methodology like other languages. You just name your classes in an intelligent way when you define them.

By the way - the above code doesn't define a class per se, but is rather just a simple object instance.

Comment: It never occurred to me order of code would prevent it from working. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

What seems to be going wrong here is that the mynamespace.init function isn't defined at the time you are hooking it up to $(document).ready.

This should work as expected:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mynamespace = {};

mynamespace.init = function() {
    $("#mybutton").bind("click",function(){     
        alert('hello');
    });
}

if(Drupal.jsEnabled){       
    $(document).ready(mynamespace.init);    
}

</script>
```

You may also consider forming it like this, as it is easier to understand (at least to me anyhow)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mynamespace = {
    init : function() {
        $("#mybutton").bind("click",function(){     
            alert('hello');
        })
};

if(Drupal.jsEnabled){       
    $(document).ready(mynamespace.init);    
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. And I also agree with you on the snippet you've given;it's looks cleaner. thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful using `$(document).ready(mynamespace.init);`. When executed in this way, `this` is no longer a reference to `mynamespace`, normally it would be equal to `window`, but jQuery do some `call` magic in the background to set it equal to `document`. It won't hurt you in this instance, but be wary of it in the future.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    mynamespace.init();
});
```

Is how I would do it.

In this case, the reason your code isn't working is that the init method of mynamespace isn't defined at the document `$(document).ready(mynamespace.init)` is called.

Comment: `$(function(){ mynamespace.init(); });` is how I would do it.   :-)

Answer (score 0):

What strikes me as odd, at least working mostly in C#, is that a namespace should not directly contain code logic. In C# it can't, that is what classes are for. So for me, having an init function on a namespace is a contradiction.

Comment: That's because namespaces don't exist in JavaScript - it's just a way to package functionality to avoid scope collisions. "Namespace" is just a borrowed term.

Comment: I understand its not enforceable, but namespace still seems like the wrong term to borrow if you are adding an init function to it. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use object as a namespace. Another way to form a namespace is to use [closures](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html):

```
(function(inner_variable_1, inner_variable_2) {

    // define whatever here, they won't pollute namespace outside this closure

})(outer_variable_1, outer_variable_2);
```

Popular example is jQuery's [noconflict-mode](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries), which enables you to use $ variable in your jQuery code without making $ a global variable, thus leaving the global $ for another use.